# Repeat a sequence of a list

Tags: python, list, loops, combinatorics

**Problem**

Given the following list:

```
l=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

I want to repeat the `n` first elements of the list `r` times, and after that, do the same for the next `n` elements of the list, and so on...

For example, for `n=2` and `r=2`:

```
result=[1,2,1,2,3,4,3,4,5,6,5,6]
```

And for  `n=3` and `r=2`:

```
result=[1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,6,4,5,6]
```

**My clumsy attempt**

```
l=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
n=3
r=2
l_new=[]
result=[]
for i in range(0,len(l),n):
    reduced=l[i:(n+i)]
    l_new.append(reduced)

for elem in l_new:
    elem_new=elem*r
    result+=(elem_new)
```

How can I improve this code? What is a more clean/efficient/good practice way of doing this?

Comment: Questions about improving otherwise working code may be better suited for [codereview.se], but be sure to follow their [content guidelines](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [How to Ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to ensure an on-topic question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```py
l=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
n=3
r=2
result=[]

for i in range(0,len(l),n):
    result += l[i:i+n]*r
```

or alternatively as a function:

```py
def repeat_sequence(l, n, r):
    result = []

    for i in range(0,len(l),n):
        result += l[i:i+n]*r

    return result

l=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
repeat_sequence(l, 3, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def flatten(arr):
    return [item for sublist in arr for item in sublist]

def flatmap(f, arr):
    return flatten(map(f, arr))

def chunk(arr, r):
    return [arr[i:i+r] for i in range(0,len(arr), r)]

def repeat_n_r_times(arr, n, r):
  return flatmap(lambda x: x * n, chunk(arr, r))
```

Comment: @Axe319 — I did, than you.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it cleanly as following.

```
l=[1,2,3,4,5,6]

def repeat_n_r_times(l, n, r):
    list_breakdown = [l[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(l), n)]
    #make copies r times 
    lst = [lst*r for lst in list_breakdown]
    # merge all sublist
    return [item for sublist in lst for item in sublist]

print(repeat_n_r_times(l, 3, 2))
# OUTPUT: [1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,6,4,5,6]
print(repeat_n_r_times(l, 2, 2))
# OUTPUT: result=[1,2,1,2,3,4,3,4,5,6,5,6]
```